# How can I unroll a Twitter thread using Python and Tweepy library?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to gather a account's tweets along with their replies, including the URLs of the photos, into a single text file. I will later convert it to HTML, but I just wrote it this way to view it.

I'm getting a missing output, I want to get all the tweets of the account that sent that tweet, along with their replies.

[as an example i want to unroll this tweet](https://twitter.com/culturaltutor/status/1621290428187414530)

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = "***********"
consumer_secret = "**********"
bearer_token = "*************"
access_token = "***************"
access_token_secret = "************"


# Authenticate to Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify=True)

tweet = api.get_status(1621290428187414530, tweet_mode="extended")

# Print the text of the tweet
print("Tweet text:", tweet.full_text)

# Get the replies to the tweet
replies = []
for reply in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='to:@culturaltutor', tweet_mode='extended',
                           result_type='recent').items(999999):
    if hasattr(reply, 'in_reply_to_status_id_str'):
        if (reply.in_reply_to_status_id_str == '1621290428187414530'):
            replies.append(reply)

# Print the number of replies
print("Number of replies:", len(replies))

# Print the replies
for reply in replies:
    print("Reply text:", reply.full_text)

\`
```

[I was expecting like that](https://threadreaderapp.com/thread/1621290428187414530.html)

Output

```
    One knows it when you see it

People that makes stuff and paint are plenty but ARTISTS are very few
Reply text: @culturaltutor Oh cool—I saw the replica of The Fountain in the Tate Modern last summer! (At least I think it’s a replica)
Reply text: @culturaltutor Was that right piece done in 1417
Reply text: @culturaltutor Do you have any pictures of failed artist from 1500s?
Reply text: @culturaltutor Is art something that you can compare? Can someone say that one piece of art is better than another one, if someone's passion an intent is in it? Sounds kinda dumb, right?

Maybe that's another point that Duchamp was trying to make with his own form of art.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Each work depicted above is an eloquent mirror of the society that produced it. In this regard, the artists are equal.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Atm, I'm currently considering "art" more like Duchamp.   It's not about intention/soul/emotion.  Instead it's more like memetics.  Treat the art/idea as an organism and its about the survival of its genetic pattern.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Modern art has moved away from the visual much more towards the psychological.
Reply text: @culturaltutor What is your take on the debate about whether it was Duchamp or Baroness Elsa von Freytag-Loringhoven? 


Reply text: @culturaltutor Beautiful thread, as usual, thank you! It put me in mind of Tristan Tzara's elaboration of the topic in Tom Stoppard's TRAVESTIES: 
Reply text: @culturaltutor skill, talent are just 2 reasons.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @threadreaderapp unroll
Reply text: @culturaltutor Bcoz we entered the era of quick gratification.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Cold War CIA psyop gone rogue.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Now try and do discussions of art without the crutch of zeitgeist. Then the task really begins. Duchamp was no more an exemplar of his time than Michelangelo was of his. Art cannot be reduced to such a capitulation to Hegelianism or just a crude historical determinism.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @umhomemsimples now look at this. This is the exact reason why I follow this page. Where in this God forsaken world, would I learn the connection between an urinal, te 1º great war, modern art and artificial intelligence???
Reply text: @culturaltutor How do you see AI replacing art?
Reply text: @culturaltutor i just got a whole history lessons and i’m all for it!
Reply text: @culturaltutor ...because the gallerygoer changes.
Reply text: @culturaltutor lack of talent
Reply text: @culturaltutor This is just what happens when the developer takes decades to release the new update. Art 2.2 when??
Reply text: @culturaltutor *laughs in cattelan
Reply text: @culturaltutor It's a nobel goal to try to redeem current art, but lest just say it, modern art is pathetic and, in many ways, disgusting.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @rattibha with lots of thanks
Reply text: @culturaltutor Short answer: Money Laundering
Reply text: @culturaltutor Any books for reading more about this?
Reply text: @culturaltutor ' , '           
Reply text: @culturaltutor Thanks. Food for thought.
Not why the mundane became art but why the discerning mortgaged their sensitivities &amp; encouraged those who started treating art as an outlet for their angst against the camera. They
replaced skill by mental gymnastics &amp; even an ape won a prize once. Sad.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Define “stop.”
Reply text: @culturaltutor They literally did not tho
Reply text: @culturaltutor Capitalism. They still make art on some level, it's just for a different purpose.
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didnt. We stopped buying.
Reply text: @culturaltutor New Republican hopefulness vs late stage capitalist despair. Can’t really compare the two to make this point.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Oh no, not you too 
Reply text: @culturaltutor ninguno, sigan trabajando
Reply text: @culturaltutor @readwise save
Reply text: @culturaltutor Duchamp just made an irony. A lot of people didn't understand the irony.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Because it's hard
Reply text: @culturaltutor Who runs the art world?
Reply text: @culturaltutor There is a case to be made that art was at first something in which we perceived with our eyes, now it seems we're moving towards a world in which art is what we see in our minds.
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didn't, the art is in the stopping of making art, *artception
Reply text: @culturaltutor I think what we see as a beautiful art, is somethint near to what our eyes can see, in nature in real, that was necessary back than, when we didn't had the photography, that changes all, the human do not need paint to see, to save memories, places or people in the future.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Because esoteric cleverness became more important than craft.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @DrJayDrNo Well, all of this “great art” was commissioned from life long artists. Whereas people sh$t on arts educations these days.
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didn’t stop. Motion film became moving paintings.
Reply text: @culturaltutor I still make art find me on instagram @ beamonicaaspiras
Reply text: @culturaltutor Degenerate mentality posing as artistic expression.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @Trinityaudiobot
Reply text: @culturaltutor Because they are all individuals with bad taste rather then serving patrons with old taste.
Reply text: @culturaltutor I don’t even know where to begin….Bravo
Reply text: @culturaltutor Wow, never would've thought to connect the industrial revolution and war to a urinal water fountain! And bringing up AI and how it will affect art is more interesting with this context.

Thanks as usual, and here's a video of this thread! 
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didn't
Reply text: @culturaltutor A slutty society can't produce culture because there's no sublimation of drives any more.

If you want art back you must restrain sexuality again.
Reply text: @culturaltutor …and what art movements will be in response to the next industrialization driven by AI ?
Reply text: @culturaltutor They forgot how.

Reply text: @culturaltutor When the cultural arbiters decided there was no such thing as objective truth.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.
We just have to take off this blindfolder called modernity and remember that urinals were made for bathrooms, not art expositions.
Reply text: @culturaltutor First you made me need to pee, then you enlightened me.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @InvestInOnG Took an Art course in Florence when I was in college.  Standing at the base of David,  one of my classmates blurted out … “Why’s his Dick so tiny”.

We were asked to leave the Accademia Gallery. 

Italians are sensitive to insults aimed at male anatomy.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Love and respect. And foreground/background. What you focus on...you get better at (both making or appreciating)

It's seeing deterioration in the artists and the consumers, to be pejorative. Or, our highs and lows now are not as high, or low, as they were hundreds of years ago.
Reply text: @culturaltutor oh no, not my boy Duchamp! 

Duchamp is to art what Martin Luther was to Christianity
Reply text: @culturaltutor Beauty is disappearing from the art world. And that can't be a good thing.


Reply text: @culturaltutor One of the absolute best accounts on twitter. Thank you for sharing such wonderful insights. Absolute food for the soul. ❤️
Reply text: @culturaltutor Sheehan you are amazing &amp; thanks for this.

As fascinating as you are, you’ve given me something much greater - hope!

In 6 months you’ve amassed a million followers.

Smart, educated, appreciative people are out there!

Aristotle was right: “Man, by his nature, desires to know”
Reply text: @culturaltutor Well Davi may need to pee at some point in the arts universe
Reply text: @culturaltutor Time
Reply text: @culturaltutor Ambos son arte solo que en contextos e ideales totalmente distintos
Renacimiento vs vanguardias del siglo XX (dadaismo). Hacen una representacion de realidades e intenciones muy distintas.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Such nonsense. I'm done.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Because art is just a concept nowadays
Reply text: @culturaltutor Michelangelo was like 'I spent 4 years on this masterpiece,' and Duchamp was like 'Hold my beer, I'll go to the toilet.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Duchamp was the GOAT. The hero we needed and deserved.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Plot twist: they didn't stop.
Reply text: @culturaltutor To be quite honest...
It took me a minute to focus on the thread after I saw the beautiful statue first....
‍♀️
Reply text: @culturaltutor What do you mean?  Someone duct taped a banana to the wall just a few years ago.
Reply text: @culturaltutor @threadreaderapp unroll please
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didn’t, people started to fall in love with splatters and pay millions for absurdities.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Drugs instead of alcohol.
Reply text: @culturaltutor They sort of complete each other... I'm sure David could do with a good pee, after all this time
Reply text: @culturaltutor This account sucks
Reply text: @culturaltutor I think you answered it with the first three words of the second tweet: Michelangelo was commissioned.
Reply text: @culturaltutor They didn’t. They create different art.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Classical artists worked for commissions and had wealthy patrons who funded them. Artists now have to sell themselves with each piece so they have to stand out from other artists and get attention. You can still get classical art if you commission it.
Reply text: @culturaltutor Damn I love this account
Reply text: @culturaltutor I never stopped
Reply text: @culturaltutor This Roman statue pfp can stay
Reply text: @culturaltutor i often bring up duchamp when AI critics argue that text-to-image generators cant be art because there’s no skill involved. there’s still a consciousness involved just using different tools and emphasizing the conceptual and creative aspects of the artistic process over rendering
Reply text: @culturaltutor Why did people stop interpreting it?
Reply text: @culturaltutor @AlexSchwartsman Não cai nesses baits de extrema-direita não, Alexandre
Reply text: @culturaltutor E desde quando é você quem deicide o que é arte?
Reply text: @culturaltutor Nobody threatens or pays them

Fascism is good at art to put it simply

Capitalism is too but doesnt care

Socialism cares but is distracted with hunger
Reply text: @culturaltutor This page threads https://twitter.com/ama03450/status/1621291052819791872
Reply text: @culturaltutor o duchamp mandou bem demais nessa, até hoje gerando dsicussões
Reply text: @culturaltutor Maybe they just realized he needed a cup for his junk
Reply text: Michelangelo was commissioned in 1501 to create a statue of David for Florence Cathedral.

Florence had recently become a republic again, and David was supposed to embody the spirit of the city, its democracy and values.

He was working for the city and the republic. https://twitter.com/culturaltutor/status/1621290434994778112
```

Comment: 'I'm getting a missing output' - Can you please explain what you were expecting and what is the actual output? It would be great if you could attach expected and actual results. In this case, the code is just one aspect, results may change due to other elements such as configuration of your browser, libraries you are referring to etc.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Thanks for advice. I added the output i expected and the actual one.